# What is this sata-like connection to a DVD drive?

Tags: sata, dvd

In this image, on top is a normal sata hdd with its connector, below it is an internal DVD drive with another connector. What is this connector? I'd like to buy a USB -> whatever-this-is adaptor so I can use it as an external DVD drive.

[image: Picture of the backside of a SATA HDD and an internal DVD drive]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its a mini power sata which you can find in dell computers. Also known as micro sata.

http://www.satacables.com/micro-sata-cable-ends-satacables.jpg

This is what you want too: http://g02.a.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1iQrVKFXXXXcyXFXXq6xXFXXXZ/USB-2-0-to-Micro-font-b-SATA-b-font-16pin-1-8-Hard-Disk-to.jpg

Comment: I'm finding them on eBay called 'slimline sata 7+6 pins' as well

Comment: I second that "7+6 pins" part, that seems important. I was unable to find it at Amazon unless I searched with that string. For example: https://www.amazon.com/LUTIONS-Slimline-Converter-Optical-Adapter/dp/B01KUIIP5I

Answer (score 0):

in lamens terms it's called ODD sata. (Optical Data Device)

if you need a standard sized connector, ebay has them at 5$ each, lol.

look up Sata to ODD sata, it won't disappoint.